# Regex (PSPad) to match tags and extract their contents, even when it contains tags

Tags: html, regex, tags, nested, pspad

In PSPad I am using regular expression to match HTML tag's contents. Problem is these tags can contain other tags (but never themselves).

The wrapping tags can be any heading (h1-6) or paragraph (p). I already managed to create working regexp to match content without other tags.

```
<(h[1-9]|p)([^>]*)>([^<]*)</(h[1-9]|p)>
```

But that does not match e.g.

```
<p><a href="#someLink">aaa</a> something else...</p>
```

I know I need to somehow negate the whole group so far I've tried these two (without success):

```
<(h[1-9]|p)([^>]*)>(^(</(h[1-9]|p)))*</(h[1-9]|p)>
<(h[1-9]|p)([^>]*)>(!(</(h[1-9]|p)))*</(h[1-9]|p)>
```

So how to properly negate the whole group/"word"?

I know I need to exclude `</h1` to `</h6` or `</p` from the inner match but I just can't  figure it out.

Any help / solution / direction / guidance will be very much appreciated - thanks! :-)

PS: PSPad does not do multiline regexps (that does not matter, but need to be considered)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - it is quite easy and "stupid", because I know the wrapping tags will not contain (nest) themselves... So this regexp that matches anything between start and end tag is enaugh:

```
<(h[1-9]|p)([^>]*)>(.*)</(h[1-9]|p)>
```